# Python trouble with str/int multiplication

Tags: python, function

So, i'm trying to take multiply a number which is specified in a variable, but whenever i multiply, it takes it as a string and multiplies the string, but when i try to make the variable into an int, syntax says it MUST be str!

I have tried turning the var into an int before the string

```
def gamble_menu():
  global dice_amount
  dice_amount = input("How many dice? (higher dice count = higher wager multiplier) ")
  gamble_dice()

def gamble_dice():
  while True:

    print(str(dice_amount)); print("1 - " + (int(dice_amount)) * 6)
    print("You must guess the number rolled from the number of dice")
    print("Multiplier = *2")
    number_guess = input("#? ")
    if (int(number_guess)) < 0 or (int(number_guess)) > dice_amount * 6:
      print("Invalid integer, try again")
```

i'm expecting it to multiply the variable as a number , but it takes it literal

Comment: if (int(number_guess)) < 0 or (int(number_guess)) > dice_amount * 6:

meant this:

if (int(number_guess)) < 0 or (int(number_guess)) > (str(dice_amount)) * 6:

Comment: You can use the **[edit]** link at the bottom of the post to update it. Please avoid putting codes or additional information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its because you are trying to concatanate a number and a string in the print function.

Try print("1 - " + str(int(dice_amount) * 6 ))

Comment: That worked! It is now working as intended, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `dice_amount` is a string. `(int(number_guess)) > dice_amount * 6` is trying to compare an integer with a string. Try `int(dice_amount)` instead.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 72, in <module>
    menu()
  File "main.py", line 51, in menu
    gamble_menu()
  File "main.py", line 26, in gamble_menu
    gamble_dice()
  File "main.py", line 31, in gamble_dice
    print(str(dice_amount)); print("1 - " + (int(dice_amount)) * 6)
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Because you can't add strings and integers together

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with

```
print("1 - " + (int(dice_amount)) * 6)
```

You can not mix str + int. if you are on python 3.7 like me try:

```
print(f"1 - {int(dice_amount) * 6}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code you included is incomplete. Please add more details. I've fixed a couple of errors, mainly to due with the way you're using strings in Python.
It's a bit unclear as to what the function is trying to do.

```
def gamble_dice(dice_amount): 

    while True:
        print(str(dice_amount)) 
        print("1 - ",  (dice_amount * 6))
        print("You must guess the number rolled from the number of dice")
        print("Multiplier = *2")
        number_guess = input("#? ")

    if number_guess < 0 or (number_guess > dice_amount * 6):
        print("Invalid integer, try again")
    else:
        print("right on!")

dice_amount = int(input("How many dice? (higher dice count = higher wager multiplier) "))

gamble_dice(dice_amount)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def gamble_menu():
  global dice_amount
  dice_amount = input("How many dice? (higher dice count = higher wager multiplier) ")
  gamble_dice()

def gamble_dice():
  while True:

    print(str(dice_amount)); print("1 - " + str((int(dice_amount)) * 6))
    print("You must guess the number rolled from the number of dice")
    print("Multiplier = *2")
    number_guess = input("#? ")
    if (int(number_guess)) < 0 or (int(number_guess)) > dice_amount * 6:
      print("Invalid integer, try again")

print("1 - " + (int(dice_amount)) * 6) # this is that str + int, it is wrong.
print("1 - " + str((int(dice_amount)) * 6)) # this that str + str, it works.
```

Try my best to help you.